# SpringToolsSuite says Column 'Nombre' cannot be null

Tags: java, android, retrofit, backend, spring-tools-4

I'm using retrofit with gson in android, i'm following a tutorial so the guy on the tutorial make it work but i can't
it looks like my json data is lost when i call the retrofit method here are my call in android

**ANDROID ACTIVITY.JAVA**

```
public void addProspecto(Prospecto p){
        prospectoService= Apis.getProspectoService();
        Call<Prospecto>call=prospectoService.addProspecto(p);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Prospecto>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Prospecto> call, Response<Prospecto> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(ProspectoActivity.this,"Se agrego con éxito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Prospecto> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Error:",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

**ANDROIDINTERFACE.JAVA**

```
@POST("agregar")
    Call<Prospecto>addProspecto(@Body Prospecto prospecto);
```

**backend in springtools java**
**ProspectoController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/prospectos")
public class ProspectoController {

    @Autowired
    private ProspectoService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/listar")
    public List<Map<String, Object>> listar(){
        return service.listar();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/agregar")
    @ResponseBody
    public String save(@RequestBody Prospecto p) {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        System.out.println(p.getNombre());
        int id=service.add(p);
        if(id==0) {
            return "No se pudo Regsitrar!";
        }
        return "Se registró con éxito!";
    }
```

**Prospecto model.java**

```
@Data
public class Prospecto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int ID;
    private String nombre;
    private String apPaterno;
    private String apMaterno;
    private String calle;
    private String numero;
    private String colonia;
    private String cP;
    private String telefono;
    private String rFC;
    private File documentos;
    private String statusProspecto;
}
```

And for the last the repository or the file where i use the sql querys :
**ProspectoDAO**

```
@Repository
public class ProspectoDAO implements ProspectoInterface {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate template;
    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> listar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Map<String, Object>>lista=template.queryForList("Select * from prospectos");
        return lista;
    }
    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> listar(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int add(Prospecto p) {
        String sql = "insert into prospectos(Nombre, apPaterno, apMaterno, Calle, Numero, Colonia, CP, Telefono, RFC, Documentos, statusProspecto)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        return template.update(sql,
                p.getNombre(), 
                p.getApPaterno(),
                p.getApMaterno(),
                p.getCalle(),
                p.getNumero(),
                p.getColonia(),
                p.getCP(),
                p.getTelefono(),
                p.getRFC(),
                p.getDocumentos(),
                p.getStatusProspecto()
                );
    }
```

Please help, i'm sending the object ''Prospecto'' with ''nombre'' and all the data needed for it and in my backend it stills says that i don't have the data

Comment: What is the definition of the bean Android side?

Comment: an easy way to see where things get broken might be if you log the requests you make in Android. See this tutorial for that: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses After you see the request you will be able to say if the client sends incorrectly or the server does not deserialize ok.

Comment: i tried it and don't know why but it gives me "cannot resolve symbol" in ''setLevel" and in "addInterceptor".

Comment: have you added the gradle dependency as described in the tutorial I linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my database the column ''nombre'' were ''Nombre'' with capitals so thats was all i guess. For anyone who have the same problem check the getters and setters and put it the same as they are in the columns database.